# How sprite memory management for COCOS2d sprites works

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a lot of sprites loaded in a scene. more than 100.
I'm trying to understand how memory management in COCOs2d works:

1) is setVisible(false) enough to remove it temporarily from memory ?

2) if a big sprite has let's say 90% of transparent pixels, is this sprite handled in memory the same way if this sprite was twice smaller but it had'd only 10% of transparent pixels. Does transparent pixels occupy memory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) is setVisible(false) enough to remove it temporarily from memory ?

No, you'd need to remove it from the node using:

```
[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

> 2) if a big sprite has let's say 90% of transparent pixels, is this
>   sprite handled in memory the same way if this sprite was twice smaller
>   but it had'd only 10% of transparent pixels. Does transparent pixels
>   occupy memory ?

Transparency is a colour with alpha set to `0.0`, so yes transparent pixels occupy the same amount of memory as opaque pixels.

Comment: FYI: sprite != texture, removing the sprite frees less than 500 Bytes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D But the OP asked about removing the sprite from memory.  Perhaps your comment belongs on his question?

Comment: I put it here because it's added info to the right answer. ;)